# Expert Openion Required: What plugin is used in this site?

Tags: html2pdf

I need to know what plugin is used in the site "www.gotresumebuilder.com". Its a print-preview displayed as image. I need to clone the same for a project of mine, where HTML will be displayed as image then will be saved as PDF, Text or Word.

When you login the site [www.gotresumebuilder.com](http://www.gotresumebuilder.com/)

**UserName:** khaled.javeed@gmail.com
**Pwd:** demo

Click on link (tab) "Format". A resume image is displayed fromated with options you select in "Template" dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done without a plug-in, but simply loading up a browser on the server with the provided URL, and executing an external process to capture a screen shot, and returning an image. You can do this in .NET using a small executable, and some native .NET features. This blog post explains more: http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/screenshot-of-webpage-with-aspnet-AID398.aspx around the image capture process.

PDFing a website is more common place with various blog posts outlining this process: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HTML2PDF.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Actually I need some solution with PHP. Anyways, the "Capture Screen Short" is a lead. Will google on these lines.